# Resize image with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put a logo in navbar and resize it by img-responsive but actually it doesnt work - image is still big. I don't wont to change size manually.

```css
/*
#logo-image {
  height: 50px;
}

*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top" style="background-color: #bc001d">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img id="logo-image" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200" /></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried `img-fluid` instead of `img-responsive`?

Comment: else, are these built-in class not enough https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/ , if not, make your own custom class like `.mh-25px {max-height:25px;} .mw-50px {max-width:50px;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the .img-responsive class.

This applies `max-width: 100%;`, `height: auto;` and `display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

Your Problem is, that the container of the image has no fixed width, so it will scale to max-width: 100% resulting in the big picture.

Another problem is, that your nav has no fixed height, so your logo will be sized leaving it as big as it is, and scaling your header.

You need to atleast define the size of your header, and all childern below the header, to use `h-100` on your image and all its parents, or size your parent of your image in a specific width, so that image-responsive can be used.

BOOTSTRAP can only resize your images responsively if you tell it, how big it can be at max.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top" style="background-color: #bc001d; height: 50px;">
  <div class="nav_container h-100">
    <a class="navbar-brand h-100" href="/">
      <img id="logo-image" class="h-100" alt="Logo" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200" /></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a screenshot? Because I tried to copy your code to my bootstrap website and it works fine. Maybe you need to use `max-height:50px; width: auto;` instead of `height` or responsiveness will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrap it's better to user class `.img-thumbnails`

but if you want to do this with `css` you can do this like below

```
.img-brand{
height:50px;
width:50px;
object-fit:contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

better to make width in % this how image will rezise depending on container width!

```
    .img-responcive{
width:20%
}
```